# Is there a way using PowerBI to use a if then within Table.SplitColumn function

Tags: powerbi

This relates to PowerBI:

I have this code (mcode not DAX):

#"Split Column by Delimiter3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns" , "Custom2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), ListB),

[Custom2 column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0u6X.jpg)

Which creates multiple columns from this list with data from the Custom2 column.

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjXus.jpg)

and this is the result

[Result of Custom2 & List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pew2g.jpg)

Now I want to add if the result in each cell is blank or null then  0 (zero) else $200.

so the result word look like

[Result Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADvxv.jpg)

Given that the code creates multiple columns at once what mcode do i need to wrap around or put inside the existing code for #"Split Column by Delimiter3"?

I can do this manually but the whole point is to make it dynamic.

I have tried List.ReplaceValue(Text.Split([Custom2],","),"0","$200", Replacer.ReplaceText))as a text does work but i don't know how to make it replace any non blank with $200

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found a solution myself:

- 1st step

use `#"Added Custom13" =Table.AddColumn(#"Duplicated Column4", "CustomTest", each List.Transform(Text.Split([Custom3Prep],","),each "$200")),`

- 2nd step

use `#"Extracted Values1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom13", {"CustomTest", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),`

All the items within the delimiter were replaced with $200.:)